# $scope var not updating on Parse update

Tags: angularjs, parse-platform, ionic-framework, angularjs-scope

I am building an app using ionic and parse. I am updating a boolean in parse based on a click. Everything works on parse end, I see the user object updated in the console after the function runs, however the scope variable is not updating until user logs out, comes back to the page, and then usually has to even refresh again just to see the $scope.isInstagramLinked updated to its true value.

Controller

```
var app = angular.module('myApp.controllers.account', []);

app.controller('AccountCtrl', function ($scope, $state, $cordovaOauth, AuthService) {

    $scope.isInstagramLinked = AuthService.user.attributes.is_instagram_linked;

    $scope.linkInstagram = function() {
        $cordovaOauth.instagram('######', [], {})
            .then(function(result) {
                console.log("Response Object -> " + JSON.stringify(result));
                    console.log(result.access_token);

                    // save the access token & get user info
                    AuthService.setInstagramAccessToken(result.access_token).then(function() {
                        console.log('Token saved!');
                    });
            }, function(error) {
                console.log("Error -> " + error);
            });
    }

    $scope.unlinkInstagram = function() {
        AuthService.removeInstagramInfo().then(function() {
            console.log('Insta unlinked');
            console.log(AuthService.user.attributes);
        });
    }
});
```

Service

```
  var app = angular.module('myApp.services.authentication', []);

    app.service('AuthService', function ($q, $http, $ionicPopup) {
        var self = {
            user: Parse.User.current(),
            'setInstagramAccessToken': function(token) {
                var d = $q.defer();

                var user = self.user;

                user.set("instagram_access_token", token);

                user.save(null, {
                    success: function(user) {
                        self.user = Parse.User.current();
                        d.resolve(self.user);
                    },
                    error: function(user, error) {
                        $ionicPopup.alert({
                            title: "Save Error",
                            subTitle: error.message
                        });
                        d.reject(error);
                    }
                });

                self.setInstagramUserInfo(token);

                return d.promise;
            },
            'setInstagramUserInfo': function(token) {
                var d = $q.defer();

                var endpoint = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self?access_token=' + token + '&callback=JSON_CALLBACK';

                $http.jsonp(endpoint).then(function(response) {
            console.log(response.data.data.username);
                    console.log(response.data.data.id);

                    var user = self.user;

                    user.set('is_instagram_linked', true);
                    user.set('instagram_username', response.data.data.username);
                    user.set('instagram_user_id', response.data.data.id);

                    user.save(null, {
                        success: function(user) {
                            self.user = Parse.User.current();
                            d.resolve(self.user);
                        },
                        error: function(user, error) {
                            $ionicPopup.alert({
                                title: "Save Error",
                                subTitle: error.message
                            });
                            d.reject(error);
                        }
                    });
            });
            },
            'removeInstagramInfo': function() {
                    var d = $q.defer();

                    var user = self.user;

                    user.set('is_instagram_linked', false);
                    user.set('instagram_access_token', null);
                    user.set('instagram_username', null);
                    user.set('instagram_user_id', null);

                    user.save(null, {
                        success: function(user) {
                            self.user = Parse.User.current();
                            d.resolve(self.user);
                        },
                        error: function(user, error) {
                            $ionicPopup.alert({
                                title: "Save Error",
                                subTitle: error.message
                            });
                            d.reject(error);
                        }
                    });

                    return d.promise;
            }

        };

        return self;
    });
```

I tried something like this at the end of the function but get an error saying Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress

```
$scope.$apply(function () {
     $scope.isInstagramLinked = false;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're assuming that the following line

```
    $scope.isInstagramLinked = AuthService.user.attributes.is_instagram_linked;
```

is going to make '$scope.isInstagramLinked' update anytime 'AuthService.user.attributes.is_instagram_linked' updates. That's not the case, though. Because 'AuthService.user.attributes.is_instagram_linked' references a primitive (boolean) value, it just assigns it - it doesn't maintain any kind of reference to it - that only happens with objects.

You need to manually set $scope.isInstangramLinked = true in the  $cordovaOauth.instagram() success/"then" handler.

tl;dr:

```
$scope.isLinked = false;

someFunction().then(function(){
   $scope.isLinked = true; // this is what you're missing
})
.error(function(err){...})
```

If you don't want to set it manually, you can also use [$scope.$watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) to watch 'AuthService.user.attributes.is_instagram_linked' for changes, and then update '$scope.isInstagramLinked' when it does.